# Getting an Error after upgrading the android studio 2.3 RC1

Tags: android, android-studio

Help me out ! I am stuck and not able to complete my project as i thought that I could do that after upgading studio..

**Error messages**

[image]
**Appl level gradle configuration**

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Test it by changing library version in your gradle file

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
}
```